# MySQL Query to display different result from multiple condition

Tags: mysql

I'm searching for a specific SQL Query to automatically set "Priority" cell value if the value of the "Days Left" is :

- 7 days or less  = High
- 14 days or less = Medium
- 30 days or less = Low
- 31 days or more = Very Low

this is my table looks like

```
Tasks    |  Due Date      |  Days Left | 
---------+----------------+------------+
AAAAA    |  20/12/2019    |      3     |
BBBBB    |  25/12/2019    |      8     |
CCCCC    |  01/01/2020    |     15     |
DDDDD    |  17/01/2020    |     31     |
```

result i want

```
Tasks    |  Due Date      |  Days Left |  Priority  | 
---------+----------------+------------+------------+
AAAAA    |  20/12/2019    |      3     |     High   |
BBBBB    |  25/12/2019    |      8     |    Medium  |
CCCCC    |  01/01/2020    |     15     |     Low    |
DDDDD    |  17/01/2020    |     31     |   Very Low |
```

current mysql query

```
SELECT
tasks,
due_date,
DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) AS days_left,
____________________________________ AS priority
```

Comment: You need to do it with `case when ... then` [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    tasks,
    due_date,
    DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) AS days_left,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) <= 7  THEN 'High'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) <= 14 THEN 'Medium'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) <= 30 THEN 'Low'
         ELSE 'Very Low' END AS Priority
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that, as written, the above `CASE` expression does not need to check both sides of the inequality range.  Rather, we capture higher priorities first, and then let the remaining cases flow to the next step in the `CASE` expression.

Comment: i use datediff function to calculate days_left, but looks like it doesnt work with CASE expression, is there any way i can automatically calculate days_left and use CASE expression from that result?

Comment: @Gnometa Please check my edited answer.  I misread your question initially (I think).